# MonoTouch library in Xcode?

Tags: c#, iphone, xamarin.ios

I am considering purchasing MonoTouch to do some iPhone programming in. I am wondering though, if I compile a static library (*.a) in MonoTouch (using C#) to call in Xcode as a standard static library.

Does anyone have any experience with this?  I have looked around with no results.  I even emailed Mono, but no response.

Many thanks,
Brett

Answer (score 1):

We have had apps go through without issue. 3.3.1 was more targeted at flash plus the EU are taking steps to stop Apple doing this and I hear there are law suites being prepared in America.

I'm not sure I understand your question though. Are you trying to use a *.a in MT? If so, you need to look at the btouch project:

http://monotouch.net/Documentation/Binding_New_Objective-C_Types

and http://code.google.com/p/btouch-library/

Here is a blogpost I wrote on bringing three20 into MT:

http://iwayneo.blogspot.com/2010/04/three20-with-monotouch.html

Answer (score -1):

I haven't kept up with the latest developments in iPhone development, but the last I heard was that Apple was denying release to the AppStore for any application that used a runtime that wasn't Objective-C/CocoaTouch.  I suggest you do some additional research first.

Comment: Yeah, been curious about that.  Mono *claims* their apps to be immune to this, so I was sort of banking on that. But then again, they are trying to sell software.